What does "UnsatisfiedDependency Error creating bean" in Spring Rest mean?
I'm developing a microservice about trainers and their messages in Spring using Rest. I have the controllers and services created (with their corresponding http request implementations created), and so far everything was working fine, apart from the tests.
I have seen that it is possible to include security in my microservice through JWT, but from here is when the problems have arrived. When I launch the tests, I am now getting the following error:
[ERROR]   MicroservicioEntrenadoresApplicationTests$BaseDatosVacia.modificarEntrenadorInexistente » UnsatisfiedDependency Error creating bean with name 'es.uma.informatica.practica3.MicroservicioEntrenadoresApplicationTests': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'restTemplateX': No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@DisplayName("En el servicio de entrenadores y sus mensajes,")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
class MicroservicioEntrenadoresApplicationTests {
    
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    // Para poder extraer el puerto de nuestra maquina donde Spring ha lanzado las pruebas...
    @Value(value="${local.server.port}")
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private EntrenadorRepository entrenadorRepo;

    @Autowired
    private MensajeRepository mensajeRepo;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    // Extraido de la solucion del profesor del CV sobre el taller de pruebas de jUnit
    private URI uri(String scheme, String host, int port, String ...paths) {
        UriBuilderFactory ubf = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory();
        UriBuilder ub = ubf.builder()
                .scheme(scheme)
                .host(host).port(port);
        for (String path: paths) {
            ub = ub.path(path);
        }
        return ub.build();
    }

    // Para aquellas consultas que requieran de un @RequestParam
    private URI uriWithParam(String scheme, String host, int port, String paths, String rP) {
        UriBuilderFactory ubf = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory();
        UriBuilder ub = ubf.builder()
                .scheme(scheme)
                .host(host).port(port).path(paths);

        String[] partes = rP.split("=");
        ub.queryParam(partes[0], partes[1]);
        System.out.println("La peticion post es: " + ub.toUriString());
        return ub.build();
    }

    // Extraido de la solucion del profesor del CV sobre el taller de pruebas de jUnit
    private RequestEntity<Void> get(String scheme, String host, int port, String path) {
        URI uri = uri(scheme, host,port, path);
        UserDetails userDetails = new User("username","password",
                                            List.of("ROLE_USER").stream()
                                                    .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                                                    .toList());
        String token = jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
        var peticion = RequestEntity.get(uri)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                .build();
        return peticion;
    }

    private RequestEntity<Void> get(String scheme, String host, int port, String path, String requestParam) {
        URI uri = uriWithParam(scheme, host,port, path, requestParam);
        UserDetails userDetails = new User("username","password",
                                            List.of("ROLE_USER").stream()
                                                    .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                                                    .toList());
        String token = jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
        var peticion = RequestEntity.get(uri)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                .build();
        return peticion;
    }

    // Extraido de la solucion del profesor del CV sobre el taller de pruebas de jUnit
    private RequestEntity<Void> delete(String scheme, String host, int port, String path) {
        URI uri = uri(scheme, host,port, path);
        UserDetails userDetails = new User("username","password",
                                            List.of("ROLE_USER").stream()
                                                    .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                                                    .toList());
        String token = jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
        var peticion = RequestEntity.delete(uri)
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                .build();
        return peticion;
    }

    private <T> RequestEntity<T> post(String scheme, String host, int port, String path, String requestParam, T object) {
        URI uri = uriWithParam(scheme, host,port, path, requestParam);
        UserDetails userDetails = new User("username","password",
                                            List.of("ROLE_USER").stream()
                                                    .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                                                    .toList());
        String token = jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
        var peticion = RequestEntity.post(uri)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                .body(object);
        return peticion;
    }
    

    // Extraido de la solucion del profesor del CV sobre el taller de pruebas de jUnit
    private <T> RequestEntity<T> put(String scheme, String host, int port, String path, T object) {
        URI uri = uri(scheme, host,port, path);
        UserDetails userDetails = new User("username","password",
                                            List.of("ROLE_USER").stream()
                                                    .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                                                    .toList());
        String token = jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
        var peticion = RequestEntity.put(uri)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                .body(object);
        return peticion;
    }

    @Nested
    @DisplayName("cuando la base de datos está vacía")
    public class BaseDatosVacia {

        @Test
        @DisplayName("error al obtener un entrenador concreto")
        public void errorAlObtenerEntrenadorConcreto() {
            var peticion = get("http", "localhost",port, "/entrenador/1");

            var respuesta = restTemplate.exchange(peticion,
                    new ParameterizedTypeReference<EntrenadorDTO>() {});

            assertThat(respuesta.getStatusCode().value()).isEqualTo(404);
        }
        
        @Test
        @DisplayName("devuelve error al modificar un entrenador que no existe")
        public void modificarEntrenadorInexistente () {
            EntrenadorDTO trainer = new EntrenadorDTO();
            trainer.setIdUsuario(123L);
            var peticion = put("http", "localhost",port, "/entrenador/1", trainer);

            var respuesta = restTemplate.exchange(peticion, Void.class);

            assertThat(respuesta.getStatusCode().value()).isEqualTo(404);
        }

        @Test
        @DisplayName("devuelve error al eliminar un entrenador que no existe")
        public void eliminarEntrenadorInexistente () {
            var peticion = delete("http", "localhost",port, "/entrenador/1");

            var respuesta = restTemplate.exchange(peticion, Void.class);

            assertThat(respuesta.getStatusCode().value()).isEqualTo(404);
        }

        @Test
        @DisplayName("inserta correctamente un entrenador")
        public void insertaEntrenador() {

            EntrenadorDTO trainer = new EntrenadorDTO();
            trainer.setIdUsuario(123L);
            trainer.setEspecialidad("Especialidad de prueba");
            
            var peticion = post("http", "localhost",port, "/entrenador", "centro=1" ,trainer);

            var respuesta = restTemplate.exchange(peticion,Void.class);

            assertThat(respuesta.getStatusCode().value()).isEqualTo(201);
            assertThat(respuesta.getHeaders().get("Location").get(0))
            .startsWith("http://localhost:"+port+"/entrenador");

            List<Entrenador> allTrainers = entrenadorRepo.findAll();
            assertThat(allTrainers).hasSize(1);
            assertThat(respuesta.getHeaders().get("Location").get(0))
            .endsWith("/"+allTrainers.get(0).getId());
        }
    }

